# Redirect secure domain to another via CNAME and an Nginx Docker Container

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy, redirect, cname-record

**Update:** I have appended a 2nd attempt at the bottom of this post. It is "working," but I would like to make my original idea work.

I am attempting to redirect an https request for a domain to another via a redirect server.

I will use `https://website.com`, `https://website2.com`, and `https://myredirectserver.com` for examples.

I have an SSL cert purchased for `website.com`, and it's DNS is CNAMED at `www` to `myredirectserver.com`. There is also an SSL cert for `mywebsite2.com`, and it currently sits on a server. All is well as a standalone domain.

`myredirectserver.com` has two Traffic Management A Records (high availability) that point to two IP addresses.

Those two IP addresses are NAT'd in a firewall to a proxy server.

On that proxy server, there is a Docker Container, running Alpine/Nginx.

The Dockerfile for the container:

```
FROM nginx:1.17.7-alpine    
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata    
ENV TZ America/Chicago    
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf    
COPY myredirectserver.com.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/myredirectserver.com.conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf    
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf    
COPY myredirectserver.com.crt /etc/nginx/ssl/myredirectserver.com.crt    
COPY myredirectserver.com.key /etc/nginx/ssl/myredirectserver.com.key    
COPY proxy_params /etc/nginx/proxy_params
```

The `docker run` portion to start it up (there are volumes mounted for dynamic config file creation via backend code):

`docker run --name=myredirectserver --restart always --log-opt max-size=50m --log-opt max-file=5 -d -v /etc/nginx/myredirectserverBuild:/etc/nginx/myredirectserverBuild -v /etc/nginx/myredirectserverSSL:/etc/nginx/myredirectserverSSL -p 8224:443 -p 8223:80 myredirectserver`

In that Docker Container, the Nginx config file is located in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/myredirectserver.com.conf`:

```
 #I DO NOT KNOW IF THIS IS CORRECT FOR WHAT I NEED
    server {
                listen 443 ssl;
    
                server_name myredirectserver.com www.myredirectserver.com;
                ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/myredirectserver.com.crt;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myredirectserver.com.key;
            }
            server {
                listen 80;
                server_name myredirectserver.com www.myredirectserver.com;
                return 301 https://www.myredirectserver.com$request_uri;
            }
    
    include /etc/nginx/myredirectserverBuild/*.conf;
```

The include file at the end contains the **original** requested domain, `mywebsite.com.conf`:

```
 ## www.mywebsite.com virtual host
        server {
            listen 443 ssl;

            server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
            ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/myredirectwebsiteSSL/mywebsite.com.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/myredirectwebsiteSSL/mywebsite.com.key;               
        }
        server {
            listen 80;
            server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
            return 301 https://www.mywebsite2.com$request_uri; <--- The redirect
        }
```

The `website2.com` domain is on the host server, and I can request that one just as normal. I just cannot figure out where I've gone wrong. I feel like it's in my Nginx config(s), but my Nginx syntax is not the greatest.
Why is my `return 301` not working and redirecting me to the domain?

**A couple of notes during troubleshooting:**

`wget 0.0.0.0:8223` returns:

```
  --2021-07-26 23:44:19--  http://0.0.0.0:8223/
Connecting to 0.0.0.0:8223... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.mywebsite2.com/ [following]
--2021-07-25 23:44:19--  https://www.mywebsite2.com/
Resolving www.mywebsite2.com (www.mywebsite2.com)... XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Connecting to www.mywebsite2.com (www.mywebsite2.com)|XX.XXX.XXX.XXX|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                                               [ <=>                                                                                                                  ]  37.56K   231KB/s    in 0.2s    

2021-07-25 23:44:20 (231 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [38461]
```

`curl --resolve www.myredirectserver.com:8223:0.0.0.0 http://www.myredirectserver.com/` returns a timeout, as does the browser.

While on the local network, entering the IP of the Docker container in the address bar (`192.168.69.140:8223`) takes me to `https://www.website2.com`.

Entering `https://192.168.69.140:8224` takes me to a security splash warning page. Click `proceed`, and it gives me a `404`.

I am at a loss because I don't know how to handle the request when it reaches the IP of the CNAME `myredirectserver.com`. How can I tell Nginx to look at the original requested domain `website.com`?

**Update (2nd attempt):**

I stopped the Docker container, and changed the `CNAME` at the `www` level in DNS to point to an already existed Highly Available IP. I'll call it `destinationserver.net`. So basically:

```
`mywebsite.com`
|
|---> CNAME 'destinationserver.net'

`destinationserver.net`
|
|----> A XX.XXX.XXX.XXX --> Firewall --> Proxy

|----> A XX.XXX.XXX.XXX --> Firewall --> Proxy
```

On the `destinationserver.net` server, I have the following in the Nginx config for `website.com`:

```
# ## www.mywebsite.com virtual host
        server {
            listen 8222 ssl;

            server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
            ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mywebsite.com.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mywebsite.com.key;
            return 301 http://www.mywebsite2.com$request_uri;
        }
        server {
            listen 8221;
            server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
            return 301 https://www.mywebsite2$request_uri;
        }
```

As I stated in the 'Update' on the first line of the question, this is "working," but it would be nice to handle these redirects in a separate space, hence the Docker container idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discarded the redirect server idea, and went instead with two things:

I added an ANAME (Alias) to the root domain so `www` requests would go to the same Highly Available traffic manager location as the non-`www` requests. Then, in the `Nginx` config, I added the following to redirect the requests:

```
# ## www.mywebsite.com virtual host
        server {
            listen 8222 ssl;

            server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
            ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mywebsite.com.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mywebsite.com.key;
            return 301 https://www.mywebsite2.com$request_uri;
        }
        server {
            listen 8221;
            server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
            return 301 https://www.mywebsite2$request_uri;
        }
```

This is working for what I need it to do, so unless anyone chimes in with a better method, I'll leave it as is.